# Natural language interface to semantic web

Tags: nlp, sparql, semantic-web

we are working on an educational project one of it's components is a  smart search engine that is placed on top sparql end points like DBpedia , imdb  ...etc

we explored some related work in how to make NLI to semantic web

- Ginseng: [A Guided Input Natural
  Language Search Engine for Querying
  Ontologies](http://www.ifi.uzh.ch/pax/uploads/pdf/publication/106/Bernstein_JenaConf_2006.pdf)
- [How Useful Are Natural Language
  Interfaces to the Semantic Web for
  Casual End-Users?](http://www.ifi.uzh.ch/pax/uploads/pdf/publication/843/Kaufmann_ISWC2007.pdf)-
- The author of the second paper wrote
  her entire PhD thesis about that
  topic: Talking to the Semantic Web –
  [Natural Language Query Interfaces
  for Casual End-users](http://www.ifi.uzh.ch/pax/uploads/pdf/publication/1384/Kaufmann_2007.pdf--)-

still we face some problems in implementations because the papers are too broad and no source code is available . so i wonder if there are some open sources  or Documented projects to learn how to build similar projects . 
or if  i can use similar techniques of  NLI to SQL databases , if so  from where to start.

Comment: You may get more help on this topic from http://answers.semanticweb.com/ where I see you have posted the same question.

Comment: the guys there are more science oriented , so i posted the Question here as well because there might be a technology tool or an NLP library that  Might help as well

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at this: http://technologies.kmi.open.ac.uk/poweraqua/

There is a open source download from there. I worked with a much earlier form of this software many years ago, but have no experience of this iteration of the technology.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you check [Text Wise](http://textwise.com/) and [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/overview.html). Text Wise is not open source though, but you can request a white paper. GATE is open source.